# Why does NetworkX automatically rotate graph when executed

Tags: matplotlib, networkx

I'm exercising the NetworkX examples found at [networkx.lanl.gov/examples](http://networkx.lanl.gov/examples/)

Each time I run the weighted_graph example, the graph appears to have rotated.
Why does the graph rotate?

Is there a way to control the rotation so that the graph is always in the same position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing is the result of the nx.spring_layout() algorithm that is being used to position the nodes.  The algorithm starts with a random position of the nodes so the result is nondeterministic.

You can, however, specify an initial position that is not random e.g. use a circular layout like this,

```
pos=nx.circular_layout(G)
pos=nx.spring_layout(G,dim=2,pos=pos) # positions for all nodes
```

and then you should get the same result every time.

Comment: Getting the same result is great.  With the spring_layout, how can you specify rotation of the graph (e.g., rotate_deg(45))?

Comment: There is no built-in option to rotate the positions.  But you have the x,y data in "pos" and could just rotate those by whatever angle you want.